# How can a helper return a value from method in Meteor?

Tags: methods, meteor, helper

I'm using Meteor 1.0.5.

I want a helper which returns some value from a method, but only to find that a helper returns value synchronously but the method returns value 
asynchronously. I don't know how to handle this.

for example, I need a helper to return the count of **ALL** posts, and I wrote a method to return 'Posts.find().count()' to help the helper because I don't want to publish all posts to the client. But, as said before, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got your point.. but you can do this:

```
Template.postsList.helpers({ posts: function() { return Posts.find(); } });

Template.postsList.helpers({ postsCount: function() { return Posts.find().count(); } });
```

While the first helper returns your "posts" data, the second returns only the "count" number (which I guess is what you're looking for, right?)

To confirm that it is working, I just simply added {{postsCount}} into a random html (like posts_list.html) file and it displayed the correct count of posts.

Cheers.

Comment: sorry I think I've missed an important point. In my example, server only publish a part of posts, not all, but your code only return the count of posts on the client, not the one (true count) on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should write a new Meteor.publish method, with the query you want to return.

But if you want to use a `Meteor.method` for this, this could be a solution.

```
if(Meteor.isClient){

    Template.example.helpers({
      count:function(){
        return Session.get('playersCount')
        }
    });

    Meteor.call('playersCount',function(err,result){
      if(!err){
         Session.set('playersCount',result)
        }
      })
}

if(Meteor.isServer){
 Meteor.methods({
      'playersCount':function(){
         return Players.find().count();
        }
      })
}
```

Here is a [Meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/6JzSzjBAMoCeuCzjc/Leaderboard) Example

Comment: thank you for this. you use the session as a temp reactive storage to hold the value, and i believe it will work on my situation. i'm interested in your suggestion with Meteor.publish method. as I know, Meteor can publish a subset of a collection, but how can it publish a derived collection, say, in this case, the count of the collection 'posts'?

Comment: You want to post just a number? why don't better make a publish with the collection, like following this [example](https://gentlenode.com/journal/meteor-21-pagination-system-with-infinite-scroll/43), so do that on the server publish the amount on post, and on the client side, do the count like always on a helper `Collection.find().count()`, this is more easy, server publish-client subscribe and count

Comment: thenks @Ethaan. but to publish the collection is not good for my case. In my header or layout, I want to show the count of ALL some kind of data, but just the count. publish ALL data for the little count may not be good enough

Answer (score 0):

You can use a closure:

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function(){
  closure.init();
};

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  foo: function(){
    return closure.value();
  }
});

var closure = function(){
  var privateValue;
  return {
    init: function(){
      Meteor.call(method,function(err,result){
        if ( !err ) privateValue = result;
      }
    },
    value: function(){
      return privateValue;
    }
  }
}();
```

When the template is rendered the closure invokes `Meteor.call` which asynchronously stores its result in `privateValue`. Then the template helper can fetch it.

This would work fine if the value only needs to be computed once in a template - not in a list of records for example. You shouldn't be doing a server call once per record in a long list, you'd want all those computations to happen as part of a subscription instead.

Comment: thanks. your solution shares the same spirit of that of @Ethaan, and your suggestion is considerable, maybe, yes, I shouldn't hope my app to watch a method-returned-value. I'll try some other ways to do it.